# "Connection Interrupted" when uploading file larger than 10mb

Tags: ubuntu, file-upload, nginx, php

I have an application (html form) that allows users to upload a file to the server. When the file is larger than 10mb, it kicks the user directly to a "Connection interrupted" page.

Server is setup as follows:

- Ubuntu Mavrick
- Nginx 0.8.54
- PHP (FPM) 5.3.5
- Zend v2.3.0

Under php.ini (for both fpm and php proper) the max-upload size and post-max is set to 20mb. Form field has a max file size of 200000000

Any ideas as to what this could be? Is this an nginx problem?

Comment: Have you set the Max Execution Time of your script to `0`?

Comment: did you set nginx to allow 10meg uploads as well? http://serverfault.com/questions/277738/limit-upload-file-size-and-redirect-user-to-error-page-if-limit-exceeds. PHP's limits only apply AFTER the webserver's. If nginx only allows 1meg, you can change PHP's all you want and you'll still never upload >1meg.

Comment: Why not upload through FTP to check where the problem is comming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nginx server config put:

```
client_max_body_size 20m;
```

Comment: Thank you! I had that line set in one virtual server, but not the key one. Much appreciated :)